# Solving Hanoi puzzle using recursion

Tags: c++, computer-science

I am currently creating a program that shows every move to solving the Hanoi puzzle. I need to show the position of each disc every move made starting with the beginning position as (A,A,A). A = first peg, B = second peg, and C = third peg. I have the program outputting the moves but not the position. How do I implement the positions into the program? Here is my code so far with my output and a diagram showing what the positions should be after each move. Number of discs is a const 3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void moveDiscs(int num,int fromPeg,int toPeg, int tempPeg){;
char position;
    if(num > 0){
        moveDiscs(num-1,fromPeg,tempPeg,toPeg);
        cout << "Move a disc from peg "<<fromPeg<<" to peg "<<toPeg<<endl;
        moveDiscs(num-1,tempPeg,toPeg,fromPeg);
    }
}
int main() {
    const int from_peg = 1;
    const int to_peg = 3;
    const int temp_peg = 2;

    moveDiscs(3,from_peg,to_peg,temp_peg);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

[image: Diagram of Positions]

Comment: I doubt this can be done without major additions to your code. The recursive solution is that at each level of solution the function believes itself to be solving a complete problem. Therefore the sub-problems represented by the recursive calls cannot be aware of the overall problem and have no ability to track the discs in the way you described.

Comment: Please do look at my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution which keeps track of each move and each pegs position
I am using stl::map  peg A has 3,2,1 peg B , empty , peg C ,empty (where the move has to be done.

Present solution is based on the constraint can be updated based on constraint change

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

map<int,deque<int>> bucket;
deque<int> A{3,2,1};
deque<int> B;
deque<int> C;



void moveDiscs(int num,int fromPeg,int toPeg, int tempPeg){;
    if(num > 0){
        moveDiscs(num-1,fromPeg,tempPeg,toPeg);
        cout << "Move a disc from peg "<<fromPeg<<" to peg "<<toPeg<<endl;
        auto val = bucket[fromPeg].front();
        bucket[fromPeg].pop_front();
        bucket[toPeg].push_front(val);
        for (auto it:bucket)
        {
            cout << it.first << "::";
            for (auto di = it.second.begin(); di != it.second.end(); di++)
            {
                cout << "=>" << *di;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        moveDiscs(num-1,tempPeg,toPeg,fromPeg);
    }
}
int main() {

    bucket[1] = A;
    bucket [2] =B;
    bucket[3] = C;
    const int from_peg = 1;
    const int to_peg = 3;
    const int temp_peg = 2;

    moveDiscs(3,from_peg,to_peg,temp_peg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 3
1::=>2=>1
2::
3::=>3
Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 2
1::=>1
2::=>2
3::=>3
Move a disc from peg 3 to peg 2
1::=>1
2::=>3=>2
3::
Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 3
1::
2::=>3=>2
3::=>1
Move a disc from peg 2 to peg 1
1::=>3
2::=>2
3::=>1
Move a disc from peg 2 to peg 3
1::=>3
2::
3::=>2=>1
Move a disc from peg 1 to peg 3
1::
2::
3::=>3=>2=>1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So you can see from Peg A (1::3=>2=>1) is moved to peg C(3::3=>2=>1)